# My GOIBIBO Flight search API is not working

Tags: angular, ionic3

I am working on project like to find Hotels, Flights, and find places according to destination location for this I am using the GOIBIBO API. All API's working fine except Flight search API. It throws an error "502 Bad Gateway". I didn't find any solution for why this happens.

Please do provide any suggestions on how to get this working. Find the link to that error which I am getting shown below.

Thanks

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Tqxf.png

Comment: This post appears to be [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) as per *Questions that lack sufficient information to diagnose the problem.* Please edit your post accordingly to add sufficient detail so that people may help you. And you should paste the code/error log directly into the question.